# How to access Library, File, and Field descriptions in DB2?

Tags: db2

I would like to write a query that uses the IBM DB2 system tables (ex. SYSIBM) to pull a query that exports the following:

LIBRARY_NAME, LIBRARY_DESC, FILE_NAME, FILE_DESC, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_DESC

I can access the descriptions via the UI, but wanted to generate a dynamic query.

Thanks.

Comment: Please indicate what platform you are running DB2 on.

Comment: I think it is iSeries. Maybe that doesn't give enough info, but I finally found the table I was looking for. Still hunting down the Library description. I'm using the QSYS2 (SYSTABLES and SYSCOLUMNS) schema and am able to get all the info above except for Library description. Do you know where that lives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with `SYSTABLES` and `SYSCOLUMNS`, there is also a `SYSSCHEMAS` which appears to contain the data you need.  Please note that accessing this information through `QSYS2` will restrict rows returned to those objects with which you have *some* access - the `SYSIBM` schema appears to disregard this (check the reference - for V6R1 it's about page 1267).

You also shouldn't need to retrieve this with a dynamic query - static with host variables (if necessary) will work just fine.

Comment: I am having trouble pulling back data from SYSSCHEMAS, but it appears to be a permissions issue (that I am working to get resolved).

Comment: @Josh - You will need `SELECT` access to either `QSYS2` or `SYSIBM` schemas, and the relevant tables, although I would have assumed a default access to at least one of them...

Comment: I seem to have access to SYSTABLES and SYSCOLUMNS, but receive this error when hitting SYSSCHEMAS: [SQL0443] *N Cause . . . . . :   Either a trigger program, external procedure, or external function detected and returned an error to SQL. If the error occurred in a trigger program, the trigger was on table QDBSSUDF2 in schema QSYS. If the error occurred in an external procedure or function, the external name is QDBSSUDF2 in schema QSYS...

Comment: The various `SYS...` objects are actually _views_ and not tables.  It appears that they are calling some sort of UDF to retrieve their data (probably dependandt on how IBM actually stores the relevant information).  Talk to your DBAs, as an error of this nature may be affecting other areas.  You may need to talk to your support Rep to resolve this, especially as the function is supposed to reside in `QSYS`.